# Hidden Markov Model - Dealing with observation lags

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I have a Hidden Markov Model with a "publication lag" (i.e. the observation "published" in period $t$ is actually measured in period $t-1$). For example, a survey asking about **current** conditions is answered at time $t-1$ but published at time $t$.

How should I think about estimating the current state $S_t$, when the observation is published? My initial thought was to decompose the problem into a filtering problem and a dynamics problem (i.e. treat it just like a prediction problem): $P(S_t|O_{0:t-1})=P(S_{t-1}|O_{0:t-1}) * P(S_t|S_{t-1})$. But the time indices are confusing (e.g. I'm performing at time $t$ an inference procedure on observations indexed through $t-1$), so I'm wondering if there's a more standard way to formulate this problem.

Comment: If the published survey results do not feed back into the evolution of the system, the fact that they are published at $t+1$ instead of $t$ is actually irrelevant.   You can shift them to be "pseudo-published" at time $t$ and run your HMM on the resulting (state-observation pairs now time-synchronized) observations.

Comment: In the hypothetical above, it sounds like I've already got the right approach (shifting to a "pseudo-index" as you note). In the real world, I suspect the survey (in this case, employment survey) affects central bank actions, which in turn affect employment (the hidden state). But that's a separate issue.